# Cannot import Tensorflow after successfull installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Tensorflow is successfully installed in a Conda environment but, I am not able to import tensorflow.
I have updated numpy also using code:`conda update numpy`. I am getting following error for code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-64156d691fe5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import data
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\data_service_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import compression_ops
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\compression_ops.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import tensor_array_ops
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\tensor_array_ops.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
  File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1475, in <module>
    _NON_AUTOPACKABLE_TYPES = set(np.core.numerictypes.ScalarType)

AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'
```

Comment: If you search of Stack Overflow for "AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'" there are a few similar questions with no answers, but some suggestions in comments. Have you tried those?

Comment: what is the version of tensorflow and numpy you have installed?

Comment: Yes ! please share tensorflow version and numpy version. Also try with following command.   pip install numpy -U

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment for tensorflow and reinstall tensorflow in that environment using below code:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow python=3.5
conda activate tf

conda install pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Then try again executing your codes. Let us know if the issue still persists.